# Why is Alert not showing on my React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react, and I've done a Form which I want to come up an alert when clicking the submit button. When I opened it on a browser through my local file it worked but when seeing on GitHub I don't get the same result, not sure why. I save it and push it to the repository. 
Here it's how it looks https://joanaoli09.github.io/milestone/

Here is the code to the Form.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Form.css";

export default class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    userName: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  };

 onSubmit = e => {
    alert("Your information has been uploaded");
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
    this.setState({
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      userName: "",
      email: "",
      password: ""
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="formcontainer">
        <form className="Form">
          <p className="register">CREATE ACCOUNT</p>
          <input
            className="input"
            name="firstName"
            placeholder="First name"
            value={this.state.firstName}
            onChange={e => this.change(e)}
          />
          <br />
          <input
            className="input"
            name="lastName"
            placeholder="Last name"
            value={this.state.lastName}
            onChange={e => this.change(e)}
          />
          <br />
          <input
            className="input"
            name="username"
            placeholder="Username"
            value={this.state.username}
            onChange={e => this.change(e)}
          />
          <br />
          <input
            className="input"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={e => this.change(e)}
          />
          <br />
          <input
            className="input"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={e => this.change(e)}
          />
          <br />
          <button className="submit" onClick={e => this.onSubmit(e)}>
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
);
  }
}
```

Comment: Neither script linked in the source code contains `alert`. Not sure what you mean by "the code is getting in the head", that's not true and wouldn't work anyway. The HTML is entirely inside `<body>`, where it belongs. Anything inside `<head>` is invisible.

Comment: that's true, why is appearing weirdly on the top of the page though? And not occupying the whole space of it.

Comment: That's default behavior for HTML: the <body> grows as tall as necessary to fit all content inside. If you want the form centered on the page vertically, you need to specifically tell the browser to do that via CSS: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-worker-w3fwb?file=/src/Form.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the `Form.js` file on that URL, you will see this:

```
onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.props.onSubmit(this.state);

  this.setState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    userName: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });
};
```

So it looks like what you have deployed to that URL and what you have posted here is not the same. You might have pushed some new code to your repo, but if the changes are not appearing on that URL, you might have forgotten to deploy them again or the deploy pipeline might have failed for some reason.

The code here is missing some bits like the `onChange` callback, but adding them back it works just fine:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    username: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
  });
  
  const handleSubmit = React.useCallback((e) => {
    alert('Your information has been uploaded.');

    e.preventDefault();
    
    setState({
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
    });
  }, []);
  
  const handleChange = React.useCallback(({ target }) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [target.name]: target.value }));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="formcontainer">
      <form className="Form">
        <p className="register">CREATE ACCOUNT</p>

        <input
          className="input"
          name="firstName"
          placeholder="First name"
          value={ state.firstName }
          onChange={ handleChange }
        />

        <input
          className="input"
          name="lastName"
          placeholder="Last name"
          value={ state.lastName }
          onChange={ handleChange }
        />

        <input
          className="input"
          name="username"
          placeholder="Username"
          value={ state.username }
          onChange={ handleChange }
        />

        <input
          className="input"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={ state.email }
          onChange={ handleChange }
        />

        <input
          className="input"
          name="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          value={ state.password }
          onChange={ handleChange }
        />

        <button className="submit" onClick={ handleSubmit }>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.input,
.submit {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 8px;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! thanks to much for your help. BTW do you know why is it appearing on the top of the page? Is it something I can change with css?

Comment: I think you are missing `min-height: 100vh`, `display: flex` and `align-items: center` into your `.App` selector.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some issues in your code here

```
       <input
        className="input"
        name="username"
        placeholder="Username"
        value={this.state.username}
        onChange={()=>this.change(e)}
      />
```

Here instead of `name="username"` it should be `name="userName"` because in

```
 change = e => {
this.setState({
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value //you are passing [e.target.name]
});};
```

And please make sure you always deploy the code again after making any changes in the repo by running `npm run deploy`